# How to define Tuple1 in Scala?

Tags: scala

I try to use `(1,)`, but doesn't work, what's the syntax to define Tuple1 in scala ?

```
scala> val a=(1,)
<console>:1: error: illegal start of simple expression
       val a=(1,)
```

Comment: you mean, you want more convenient syntax than `Tuple1(1)` ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For tuple with cardinality 2 or more, you can use parentheses, however for with cardinality 1, you need to use `Tuple1`:

```
scala> val tuple1 = Tuple1(1)
tuple1: (Int,) = (1,)

scala> val tuple2 = ('a', 1)
tuple2: (Char, Int) = (a,1)

scala> val tuple3 = ('a', 1, "name")
tuple3: (Char, Int, java.lang.String) = (a,1,name)

scala> tuple1._1
res0: Int = 1
scala> tuple2._2
res1: Int = 1
scala> tuple3._1
res2: Char = a
scala> tuple3._3
res3: String = name
```

---

To declare the type, use `Tuple1[T]`, for example `val t : Tuple1[Int] = Tuple1(22)`

Answer (score 2):

A tuple is, by definition, an ordered list of elements. While `Tuple1` exists, I haven't seen it used explicitly given you'd normally use a single element. Nevertheless, there is no sugar, you need to use `Tuple1(1)`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a valid use case in Spark that requires Tuple1: create a dataframe with one column.

```scala
import org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vectors

val data = Seq(
    Vectors.sparse(5, Seq((1, 1.0), (3, 7.0))),
    Vectors.dense(2.0, 0.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0),
    Vectors.dense(4.0, 0.0, 0.0, 6.0, 7.0)
  )
data.toDF("features").show()
```

It will throw an error:
*"value toDF is not a member of Seq[org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vector]"*

To make it work, we have to convert each row to Tuple1:

```scala
val data = Seq(
    Tuple1(Vectors.sparse(5, Seq((1, 1.0), (3, 7.0)))),
    Tuple1(Vectors.dense(2.0, 0.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0)),
    Tuple1(Vectors.dense(4.0, 0.0, 0.0, 6.0, 7.0))
  )
```

or a better way:

```scala
val data = Seq(
    Vectors.sparse(5, Seq((1, 1.0), (3, 7.0))),
    Vectors.dense(2.0, 0.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0),
    Vectors.dense(4.0, 0.0, 0.0, 6.0, 7.0)
  ).map(Tuple1.apply)
```